# Find blank cell, vlookup, copy, paste

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

first off i am not by any means knowledgeable in vba, i can record a macro and find what i need on the web and make some tweaks or paste codes together as needed but having trouble with what im trying to do which is

trying to create a excel vba marco to

1. below a certain cell find the first blank cell in a col on one worksheet
2. take the value in the same row in another col
3. match it a col on another worksheet
4. in the same row in another col copy all cell down to first blank cell
5. go back to 1st worksheet where the 1st blank cell was found and paste the data

ex
ws1 col D is searched below cell D8 and D24 a blank cell was found
the data in B24 is matched or vlookup in ws2 col C and matches C7
so F7 and every cell down in the same col that contains data is copied
and pasted in the previous blank cell on ws1

the data in ws2 will always be different each time the macro is run

any help in part or whole would be greatly appreciated 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You have identified 5 questions you might like to ask. The thing to do is to ask five questions each of which should be supported by research and the code you wrote. So, since you asked a non-question, which will surely be deleted by the moderators for lack of focus and compliance with forum rules I shall give you a non-answer to your first question.

(1) You identify a "certain cell". That is rather vague. There are more than 1.4 million cells even on a single worksheet. Any of them may become your "certain" cell by the time you decide to think about the problem. Once you start programming you will hit this hurdle and find a solution. You shouldn't ask for a solution from here because no one can know what is "certain" for you.

(2) The "first blank cell in a column is found with this code. It presumes that the "certain cell" is A10.

```
Dim FirstBlank As Range
Set FirstBlank = ActiveSheet.Cells(10, "A").End(XlDown)
```

(3) However, it's quite uncommon to look for the first blank cell *below* a certain cell. Most of the time one looks for the last used cell at the end of a certain column.

```
Dim LastUsed As Range
Set LastUsed = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(XlUp)
```

The difference is that FirstBlank will be a blank cell anywhere in a used column. `FirstBlank.Row` will only be the same as `LastUsed.Row + 1` if there are no blank cells above `LastUsed` in column A.

As you now see, you have come to the party rather ill prepared. The help this non-answer offers is extremely limited for this reason. I hope you will now understand why no one wants to attend to all five of your non-questions. It's just too much work for too little, if any, return.

Nevertheless, the help I did intend to give, and hope you will find useful, concerns how to tackle a VBA project and how to tap into the help so abundantly available on this site. To find the right question is often half the answer because no answer can be better than the question that provoked it.